# I need more IP addresses. Can I change my mask from 192.168.x.0/24 to /16? Why not?

Tags: windows, networking

I'm using 192.168.x.x and have exhausted the IP pool.  Since 192.168.0.0/16 is all private, why can't I just change the mask to 255.255.0.0 and start allocating out 192.168.x+1.x IPs?

Edit: I realise that this would preclude me from linking to any other 192.168.x.0/24 networks

Comment: Who told you that you couldn't?

Comment: No-one except convention.  I've never seen a 192.168/16 internal range and I'm nervous.

Comment: The only issue you might have would be your router (if it's not serious) choking on NAT sessions, a /16 is huge though, why not try a /22 first?

Comment: Why not add static routes for other /16 networks?

Comment: You are helping Cisco, Juniper, and others promote their "flat network" back to basics approach without even knowing it.

Comment: And to think that I mocked the Cisco exams for being all pencil and paper endless subnetting examples...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you can use a /16, or /23, /22 etc. if you want, I know we have at least a couple of /23's in place and it works fine. Obviously you'll have to alter your netmasks everywhere and especially on your router/s but this is very commonly done.

I personally wouldn't go the whole hog and use a /16, as you say it could cause problems if you're using 192.168.x.y addresses elsewhere, so just choose a /23 or /22 and that should last you a long while.

Comment: Also keep in mind to update odd and end devices like printers and multifunction devices. Seems those get forgotten the most.

Comment: Agree, and regarding the /23 or /22, since the OP didn't state WHICH 192.168.x.0/24 network they are using, they need to be aware of what it would mean to switch to such a mask, or even the /16.  If they started with a 192.168.2.0/24 and changed it to a /22 they need to be aware that the range is going to encompass 192.168.0.0-3.255 now and won't *start* with 2.0.  The OP just needs to understand basic subnetting to handle their need.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck in a classfull IP addressing frame of mind and looking at going to 172.16 or 10.  As it happens the network is on 192.168.0.x, so I can go to /23 and only change the subnet masks which will hopefully make life slightly easier.

Comment: @BlueCompute Since you actually hit the max, just doubling your pool (/23) seems a bit low. I agree you probably don't need a /16, but as long as you're changing the mask anyway, might as well make it a /22 or even /20.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing stops you doing this - with private address ranges, such as the 192.168.0.0/16 netblock and the 10.0.0.0/8 netblock. Technically you could use non private address space - especially behind an address translating firewall - but it's rude and may become a massive nuisance.

192.16.0.0/24 is a common address range to use. But that's all. People commonly use /24 address blocks, because it neatly maps to the IP address range octets. A netmask is a bit mask that says the first (24 in this case) bits are 'network' and the remainder are 'local subnet'.

That basically means 192.168.0.0/24 is 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.255. Another common convention is to adopt '.1' as the gateway, and '.255' as the broadcast. 
Drop your netmask to 23 bits though, and you double the size of your subnet - 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.1.255. Each bit doubles the size. So whilst a /24 contains 256 addresses (8 'bits worth') - a /16 leaves 16 bits for host - 65,535 addresses.

The same is true of /16 and /8 - they map nicely to the octets of the dotted quad IP format. They are known as class A, class B and class C address ranges and once upon a time, when the internet was a much smaller place, that's all there was. Which is why you'll see a lot of (established) organisations have a /16 or class B, despite - probably - not using most of it on the public Internet.

Comment: While I applaud your detail, you should start with the "answer" and then include the necessary or extraneous details after the answer itself.  So I would suggest making your `"Nothing stops you doing this"` your first sentence and explain why the OP can do this, rather than giving an explanation of what subnetting is.

Comment: Fair point. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Also, it is not entirely true. It's not the subnet size /8 /16 /24 that defined classes A, B, C, it's also the address space assigned to it. Have a read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_Network). And there is no such Thing as class A, B, C anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The whole subnet class thing (A, B, C) is something from the past [See wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network). It was superseded by CIDR (Classless Inter Domain Routing) [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

This means that in "today's" world, you can subnet your private network with whichever network mask that suits you.